# Run configuration for iosApp is not available on Fleet

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform, jetbrains-fleet

I just created a Compose Multiplatform project using [Kotlin Multiplatform wizard](https://kmp.jetbrains.com/). Then I opened it in Fleet and enabled the [Smart Mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/fleet.html#enable-smart-mode). But in run configurations there isn't the **iosApp** configuration as mentioned in [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/fleet.html#run-your-project)

I followed the documentation to the letter but the **iosApp** configuration is not there:

[image: Fleet Run Configurations]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to **Import Gradle Project** action (Goto → *Action...* action):

[image]

Comment: Well, I had to build the project once in Xcode. It fixed my problem.